# CSS Diagonal Gradient with white space

Tags: css, background-image, gradient, linear-gradients

I need help recreating this background gradient with CSS (don't mind the gray boxes)

[image: Gradient]
At the moment my code looks like this, but the colors go from left to right and not bottom to top like in the image, if I change the degrees the whole direction changes:

```
 body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 32%,
    rgba(211, 71, 83, 1) 32%,
    rgba(98, 76, 94, 1) 52%,
    rgba(59, 70, 92, 1) 69%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 69%
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a straight gradient and rely on clip-path to create the shape:

```css
html:before {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  inset:0;
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue);
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 0,50% 100%,0 100%)
}
```